# Nvidia driver; Unable to load info from any available system

Tags: debian, nvidia

I can't open nvidia-settings:

```
 ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

This is how I installed the driver:

I installed **nvidia-detect**, ran it and it showed the following output:

```
  Detected NVIDIA GPUs:
  02:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX230] [10de:1d11] (rev a1)

  Checking card:  NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX230] (rev a1)
  Your card is supported by the default drivers.
  It is recommended to install the
    nvidia-driver
package.
```

I then proceeded to apt install the nvidia-driver and rebooted the system.

inxi -G output:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP108M [GeForce MX230] driver: nvidia v: 418.113 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: intel resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics (Whiskey Lake 3x8 GT2) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 18.3.6
```

sudo dkms status output:

```
nvidia-current, 418.113, 4.19.0-9-amd64, x86_64: installed
```

System info:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) x86_64 
Kernel: 4.19.0-9-amd64
```

I have tried purging and re-installing it but it's always the same.

Comment: Please try asking at https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148

Comment: Hi, please let me know if you have been able to solve it. I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

your error message says:

> ```
> It is recommended to install the
>      nvidia-driver
> ```

and indeed, i found that installing the `nvidia-driver` package (in addition to the kernel-modules) helps tremendously.

the nvidia kernel-modules (e.g. `nvidia-kernel-dkms`) are *required* but not *sufficient*.

Comment: i wonder why that got downvoted. it's not like my answer is a snarky remark about "read the f*ing error message", but an actual tested fix for at least one occurence of the problem.

Comment: It got downvoted because you didn't read the Q properly. He HAD installed them.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. i read the sentence "apt install **the** nvidia-driver" (emphasis mine), that they installed *some* package containing *a* nvidia driver, not necessarily the `nvidia-driver` package.